# Can we use an interrogative sentence after "but"?

Tags: conjunctions, negation, interrogatives, run-on-sentences

Is it grammatically correct that an interrogative sentence comes after "but"?

For example:

- I don't like this picture but do you like it?
- I don't know the way to the place but do you know that?
- I don't want to cooperate with the person but what about you?

I sometimes use these sentences but I'm not sure these are correct English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the cases mentioned above in your question I would replace *but* with a semicolon.

> I don't like this picture; do you like it?
>
> I don't know the way to the place; do you know that?
>
> I don't want to cooperate with the person; what about you?

And if you don't like semicolons or think that they are weird, you can always replace them with periods.

> I don't like this picture. Do you like it?
>
> I don't know the way to the place. Do you know that?
>
> I don't want to cooperate with the person. What about you?

I think the usage of 'but' in compound sentences in your case is not very good, because we use 'but' when the parts of the phrase are in some kind of strong opposition. E. g. 'Mary doesn't like the ice-cream, but I do.'

Comment: So, my usage is grammatically almost incorrect, right?

Comment: It may be, but I am not a professional in English. It is possible that someone could give you a better answer.